# How to prevent activity from destroy when mobile screen goes sleep

Tags: java, android

I am developing a app. This should be run even screen goes to sleep. 
But this is not happening with my app, the app is finishing automatically if screen goes sleep. 
I googgled for this query but didn't find any relevant. Please some one suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: put your code inside Services.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand you can force device not to sleep

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
wl.acquire();
```

make sure to use the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and to release the wakelock when you are done

```
wl.release();
```

Comment: But if this app is to be marketed to users, then this isn't really going to be user friendly..

Comment: it depends on your needs what does your app do?

Comment: @ Warlock, thank's here for answer. I think your solution is keep mobile awake. I want app can go to screen off but it should not destroy the activity. If I am unlocking the screen my app should be there untill I didn't not closed manually. Please let me know if I confused you.

Comment: the behaviour you want is already the default behaviour for android activity, when the screen locks your activity goes to pause and when you unlock screen it will call onResume(), i guess you might ovverided onPause to call finish()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when the Android system needs memory, it can kill the application.

Read here about the [Process Life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) for an Android application, which gives the various states an Android application is in, and at what point it can be destroyed.

You could however, control the significance of your application so that it can live longer
You do this by implementing `Service`. It provides two main features(from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)):

- A facility for the application to tell the system about something it
  wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not
  directly interacting with the application). This corresponds to calls
  to Context.startService(), which ask the system to schedule work for
  the service, to be run until the service or someone else explicitly
  stop it.
- A facility for an application to expose some of its functionality to
  other applications. This corresponds to calls to
  Context.bindService(), which allows a long-standing connection to be
  made to the service in order to interact with it.